# How to store logged user in Odoo14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to store the currently logged user into a many2one field using compute method. It's working fine if i define the Mnay2one field without the store="True" parameter. Actually, i need to save it.

Here is the code:

```
    def get_logged_user(self):
          for rec in self:
              print('inside get_logged_user---------------',rec.env.user.name)
              rec.logged_user_id = rec.env.user.id

    logged_user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users',string="Logged user",store=True,compute="get_logged_user")
```

Comment: If you set store=True on your field. You must used @api.depends to trigger the call of the compute.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

If you only need to control visibility of a field/button inside QWeb view you could archive this without dedicated field. You could use `context.get('uid')` to get current user like this:

```xml
<button ... invisible="context.get('uid') == assigned_user_id">
```

But if you need to store logged-in user inside a field you could use `default` instead of `compute`.
Something like this:

```py
logged_user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Logged user", default=lambda self: self.env.user)
```

Note usage of lambda function.

If you really need to use `compute` field with `store=True` you need to specify when to compute it. By using `api.depends` decorator you can trigger it when `your_field` is changed.

```py
@api.depends('your_field')
def get_logged_user(self):
```

But I would ask a question why do you need to store logged-in user inside a field? If you could provide more context maybe we could suggest different solution.

Comment: here is my requirement, i have a button and assigned_user on form view, I need to make the button visible only if the assigned user and logged user are same.

Comment: In that case I think dedicated field isn't necessary. Check edited answer for alternative approach.

Comment: I solved with depends option.  context didn't work in attrs attribute since  I had more than one condition.